# Update table from table with multiple rows of data

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a function with several product ID's in a table. I want to perform this update and set these variables to the desired product ID's. Right now, this updates only the first productID from my function that splits the multiple values of my variable. I'm aware a CTE would be ideal here, but I'm not great at the syntax.

My desired outcome is for each value in @CSV, execute the update statement. Any assistance would be great.

```
DECLARE 
        @MaxAllowance INT = 25,
        @AllowanceType INT = 2,
        @AllowancePeriod INT = 2,
        @Account_ID INT = 13379,
        @CSV VARCHAR(50) = '506,280,281,282,286',
        @count INT 

                DECLARE @DiscountClass_ID INT =
        (
            SELECT DiscountClass_ID FROM Account WHERE Account_ID = @Account_ID
        );

SELECT @count =
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.FN_csv_tolist(@CSV)
            );


declare @ProductID int
declare @rn int

declare ItemCursor cursor local static forward_only read_only for 
select Value,
       row_number() over(partition by Value order by Value) as rn
FROM dbo.FN_csv_tolist(@CSV)

open ItemCursor

fetch next from ItemCursor
into @ProductID, @rn

WHILE @count > 0
begin
  update dbo.ProdTerm
  SET MaxAllowance = @MaxAllowance,
      AllowanceType = @AllowanceType,
      AllowancePeriod = @AllowancePeriod
      WHERE Product_ID = @ProductID
  SET @count = @count - 1;
  fetch next from ItemCursor
  into @ProductID, @rn
end

close ItemCursor
deallocate ItemCursor
```

Comment: You are not setting variables here - you are assigning them to columns within the selected rows. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: What does `dbo.FN_csv_tolist` return exactly? Presumably you want to return that into a table (or CTE) and then join to it to do your update.

Comment: @Leonidas199x That returns a table of one column and 5 rows for each 'Product ID' under CSV variable

Comment: @SMor updated question

Comment: @Brenner is that code accurate to how you use it, or have you changed it for the purpose of your question? Presumably the `@CSV` variable is coming from somewhere else, and not being set like that?

Comment: @Leonidas199x yes these values could be any ID and the user will use the Sproc to input their desired product IDs with the static allowance variables. These values are not meant to be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your code, I am not sure of the reason for the need of a cursor, as the code could be a lot simpler. One way would be:

```
DECLARE @MaxAllowance INT = 25,
    @AllowanceType INT = 2,
    @AllowancePeriod INT = 2,
    @CSV VARCHAR(50) = '506,280,281,282,286';

WITH Test
AS
(
    SELECT [Value]
    FROM dbo.FN_csv_tolist(@CSV)
)

UPDATE PT
SET MaxAllowance = @MaxAllowance,
    AllowanceType = @AllowanceType,
    AllowancePeriod = @AllowancePeriod
FROM dbo.ProdTerm AS PT
INNER JOIN Test AS T ON PT.Product_ID = T.Value;
```

Comment: That is simpler, however, the end goal of this is the user will input their own product IDs and won't be able to hardcode the union statement.

Comment: You could look at using the function `dbo.FN_csv_tolist(@CSV)`, or, build a collection of the IDs and pass it to a sproc or similar. You would need to give more info around how the user is entering the product IDs for me to be able to assist.